# Moving a log file outside of Docker container on EC2

Tags: docker, nginx, logging

I have a django application running inside of a docker container on an EC2. When I ssh into my Ec2, I  `docker ps` find my docker container and then run `exec -it [docker-image] sh`. Once inside, I have a directory called /logs, that has a log I want to send to a dashboard I'm running on a remote server. I was able to scp the log.file to the remote server inside of the docker container. But I want to be able to send this log.file to my user directory on my EC2, for example /home/ec2-user so that I can use rsync or some other method to continuously update my logs on the remote server.

I'm a bit of a n00b with docker. Can someone explain to me how I can send the log.file inside my container outside of it, for example, to my ec2 home directory? From there, I would just write a bash script that runs on a chron and would just scp the log.file to my remote server every minute (or whatever interval of time).

#2, I cannot, for the life of me, find where my nginx log files are. On the Ec2, I don't have an nginx directory in /var/log or in /etc. Does anyone know where the nginx access.log files are inside of the docker container?

Thanks!

Comment: You can run `docker cp CONTAINER_NAME:/logs/log-file .` to copy the file to wherever you're running docker. Would something like that work?

Comment: If you're running the Docker Hub `nginx` image, by default it writes its logs directly to the container's stdout.  You can retrieve them with `docker logs`, and popular log-management systems (fluentd, logstash) should know how to retrieve them as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks. I've read that about Nginx writing to stdout but I actually don't see the logs streaming in my console. I may not fully understand what's happening with stdout but I thought if it's being written directly to stdout, I would see them being streamed in the console.

Comment: @tentative that would work. Ultimately, I am trying to pipe log files from the service running inside the container to an external server where I can parse those logs and then put them in a dashboard, like a GoAccess set-up. I want to create a live stream, and know how to do that with GoAccess already. But my issue is piping the log file from outside of the container to somewhere else...